# How to fix 'Error(s) in loading state_dict for AWD_LSTM' when using fast-ai

Tags: python, machine-learning, torch, fast-ai, modelstatedictionary

I am using fast-ai library in order to train a sample of the IMDB reviews dataset. My goal is to achieve sentiment analysis and I just wanted to start with a small dataset (this one contains 1000 IMDB reviews). I have trained the model in a VM by using [this tutorial](https://docs.fast.ai/text.html).

I saved the `data_lm` and `data_clas` model, then the encoder `ft_enc` and after that I saved the classifier learner `sentiment_model`. I, then, got those 4 files from the VM and put them in my machine and wanted to use those pretrained models in order to classify sentiment.

This is what I did:

```py
# Use the IMDB_SAMPLE file
path = untar_data(URLs.IMDB_SAMPLE)

# Language model data
data_lm = TextLMDataBunch.from_csv(path, 'texts.csv')

# Sentiment classifier model data
data_clas = TextClasDataBunch.from_csv(path, 'texts.csv', 
                                       vocab=data_lm.train_ds.vocab, bs=32)

# Build a classifier using the tuned encoder (tuned in the VM)
learn = text_classifier_learner(data_clas, AWD_LSTM, drop_mult=0.5)
learn.load_encoder('ft_enc')

# Load the trained model
learn.load('sentiment_model')
```

After that, I wanted to use that model in order to predict the sentiment of a sentence. When executing this code, I ran into the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for AWD_LSTM:
   size mismatch for encoder.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([8731, 400]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([8888, 400]).
   size mismatch for encoder_dp.emb.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([8731, 400]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([8888, 400]).
```

And the Traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/SentAn/mainApp.py", line 51, in <module>
    learn = load_models()
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/SentAn/mainApp.py", line 32, in load_models
    learn.load_encoder('ft_enc')
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\py_code\env\lib\site-packages\fastai\text\learner.py", line 68, in load_encoder
    encoder.load_state_dict(torch.load(self.path/self.model_dir/f'{name}.pth'))
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\py_code\env\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 769, in load_state_dict
    self.__class__.__name__, "\n\t".join(error_msgs)))
```

So the error occurs when loading the encoder. But, I also tried to remove the `load_encoder` line but the same error occurred at the next line `learn.load('sentiment_model')`.

I searched through the fast-ai forum and noticed that others also had this issue but found no solution. In [this post](https://forums.fast.ai/t/running-imdb-notebook-under-10-minutes/8566/21) the user says that this might have to do with different preprocessing, though I couldn't understand why this would happen.

Does anyone have an idea about what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

It seems vocabulary size of data_clas and data_lm are different. I guess the problem is caused by different preprocessing used in data_clas and data_lm. To check my guess I simply used

data_clas.vocab.itos = data_lm.vocab.itos

Before the following line

learn_c = text_classifier_learner(data_clas, AWD_LSTM, drop_mult=0.3)

This has fixed the error.

Comment: This seems like a good idea and I don't think I tried it back then. To be honest, I gave up trying to use the fast-ai library but I am pretty sure that the preprocessing was the same. Anyway, thank you for your answer!

Comment: I had the same issue. This answer solved the problem.